# How to get height of a div with overflow hidden?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div as you will see in the jsfiddle, and I need to get the height of entire div(visible+overflowed).I tried some JQuery code but I can only get the visible height. How can I solve this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var scrolled = 0;
  $(".down").on("click", function() {
    scrolled = scrolled + 150;
    $("#container").animate({
      scrollTop: scrolled
    });
  });

  $(".up").on("click", function() {
    scrolled = scrolled - 150;
    $("#container").animate({
      scrollTop: scrolled
    });
  });

});
```

```css
#container {
  border: solid 1px red;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  height: 400px;
  width: 300px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.cent {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="up">UP</button>
<div id="container" class="cent">
  <img id="image1" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/sports/1/">
  <img id="image2" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/fashion/1/">
  <img id="image3_small" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/city/1/">
  <img id="image4" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/sports/1/">
  <img id="image5" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/fashion/1/">
  <img id="image6" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/city/1/">
  <img id="image1" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/sports/1/">
  <img id="image2" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/fashion/1/">
  <img id="image3_small" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/city/1/">
  <img id="image4" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/sports/1/">
  <img id="image5" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/fashion/1/">
  <img id="image6" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/city/1/">
  <img id="image1" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/sports/1/">
  <img id="image2" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/fashion/1/">
  <img id="image3_small" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/city/1/">
  <img id="image4" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/sports/1/">
  <img id="image5" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/fashion/1/">
  <img id="image6" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/city/1/">
  <img id="image1" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/sports/1/">
  <img id="image2" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/fashion/1/">
  <img id="image3_small" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/city/1/">
  <img id="image4" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/sports/1/">
  <img id="image5" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/fashion/1/">
  <img id="image6" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/city/1/">
  <img id="image1" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/sports/1/">
  <img id="image2" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/fashion/1/">
  <img id="image3_small" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/city/1/">
  <img id="image4" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/sports/1/">
  <img id="image5" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/fashion/1/">
  <img id="image6" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/city/1/">
</div>
<button class="down">Down</button>
```

Any advice is highly welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `scrollHeight` instead ([a DOM element property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.scrollHeight)):

```
$(selector)[0].scrollHeight
```

so in your example:

```
var height= $("#container")[0].scrollHeight;
```

or (as Vohuman points out):

```
var height= $("#container").prop("scrollHeight");
```

Comment: Or `$( "#container" ).prop('scrollHeight')`.

Comment: hmmm I found something weired: on js fiddle your example works but not on my siite. CSS,HTML and Jquery is almost 100% same....I tried also scrollHeight before.

Comment: @Petre Gabriel: I would recommend jQuery 1.11.n for best features and compatibility.

Comment: hmm actually JQ version was not the problem: when I refresh to get the height on console, I still get the visible one, but when I go to another page and hit Back on browser, like 50% of the times when I do that I get entire height. If I refresh 2-3 times entire height is shown in console, but after that shows the visible height...any solution?

Comment: @Petre Gabriel: Best post that one with your JSFiddle as a new question. Cheers

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie: I smell sarcasm?:D what I wrote there is true. I really need that total height for my code to work. I know it sounds  weired, but thats what is happen. So, your code works,but not when I refresh the page......

Comment: @Petre Gabriel: No sarcasm intended. You now have a new set of circumstances after using the code I suggested. List that as a specific new question e.g. "Why don't I always get the scrollHeight when refreshing" and supply the details you mentioned. Asking about a new issue, on a closed question, won't get you the response you desire. Cheers.